# Tinymce Preview plugin button

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Iam using jquery tinymce in my django Application. There is a default plugin named "preview" in tinymce and it works fine.

I want 1 button named "Preview" near to submit (at the end of the page) and i want this new preview button should do the same operation as plugin"preview". Anyone help me how to give the link in the new button as same as in plugin preview?

Thanks in advance!...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your button and give this to the onClick event:

```
tinymce.get('your_editors_id').execCommand('mcePreview');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily what you're shooting for exactly; but this question & answer landed me a strategy for implementing a preview button on the toolbar, like so:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.editor",
    plugins: 
    [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    allow_script_urls: true,
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | styleselect ",
    toolbar2: "PreviewButton",
    setup: function(editor)
    {
        editor.addButton('PreviewButton',
        {
            text: "Preview",
            onclick: function()
            {
                editor.execCommand('mcePreview');
                return;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Again - not an external button like you were looking for, but hopefully someone else will find this solution helpful if they land on this question.